# Is the code signature crucial to prove ownership?

Tags: ios, signing

I am developing an iOS game (closed source), but working in partnership with publisher company. The ownership should be mine and then I should authorize the publisher to just distribute the game in some countries/regions via legal agreement. However I need to sign the code with p12 cert and a provisioning profile... The publisher sent me their certificates, but is it safe to use them since I should remain the owner of the game?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "safe" here. This seems to be a legal question, in which case you will need to discuss with your lawyer and Stack Overflow can't be helpful. It will depend on your contract, the rest of the facts, and the jurisdiction.

Answer (score 0):

To be on the safer side I would suggest you to add the publisher's apple Id to your team(in your apple Id). You can then assign particular roles to the publisher and restrict the actions which can be performed. You car get more detailed information from below sources :

https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

https://sandeshsardar.com/2017/04/01/how-to-manage-your-developer-account-team/

Hope this helps you in some way.

Comment: Do you have any reference on why this would be "safer" (for any definition of "safer")? I don't see anything in the links about how this arrangement impacts ownership. This feels like a legal question, and these links don't seem to touch on any legal issues.

Comment: @RobNapier The link describes how the owner of the apple account can restrict another apple id(added to his/her team) from performing some actions. Here if the owner just signs the app bundle with other's p12 then there would be no proof of ownership but in case of team members added the owner can always show that who is the owner here if it comes to legal matters in future.

Comment: "if the owner just signs the app bundle with other's p12 then there would be no proof of ownership." I don't understand what principle of law you're applying here. I agree that it "makes sense," but that doesn't have anything to do with legal matters. Have you worked with a lawyer on something like this case? My experience going down these kinds of roads with corporate lawyers is that the law is almost nothing like computer people believe it is. I strongly recommend asking a lawyer how the law applies here.